# Cumulocity data export

Tags: iot, cumulocity

I noticed a limit of 2000 records per API call for getting collections out of Cumulocity. Will we be constrained to these limits or is there any other batch API available?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get more than 2000 records for a single collection request at the moment. But you can specify a more direct query e.g. by time and grab it in multiple requests if it exceeds the 2000 records.

Example:

```
/measurement/measurements?dateFrom={dateFrom}&dateTo={dateTo}
```

Another way would be to get data continuously pushed to you. You can use the real-time API http://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/real-time-notifications/